# Delete folder show "You need permission to perform this action" but I've set Security - All Users - Allow Full Control

Tags: windows

Why I can't delete folder with Security - All Users - Allow Full Control?

System show `You need permission to perform this action`.
[image]
[image]

Genernal
[image]

Security Edit
[image]

Security Advanced
[image]

But I've set Security - All Users - Allow Full Control
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why I can't delete the folder with Security - All Users - Allow Full Control?

It appears this folder was either originally owned by a user that doesn't exist on the system or was transferred from another Windows machine.  This is evident by the fact the owner is being displayed by a SID (User Security Identifier).

Furthermore, the advanced security settings which define the access control list for the folder and its contents indicate Users on the desktop only have Read & Execute permissions.

You will want to change those permissions to Full Control, and change the owner to the user group `DESKTOP-IOP1930\Users`.  You will also likely want to replace the child object permissions at this time.  **In order to do this, you must be an Administrator, it will not be possible with a user in the `Users` group.**

> [image]

Comment: One of the reasons you had a permission problem, other than the fact the owner didn't exist on the system, is you had 2 permission entries for the same user group.  `Deny` permissions always are above `Allow` permissions.  Basically, while `DESKTOP-IOP1930\Users` did have full access to the folder, it was removed by the second permissions that explicitly only granted `Read & execute` permissions which were inherited from the permissions from the `D:\`.  I am sure there is an explanation for the reason File Explorer indicated you did have permissions.  I just don't have time to do that tonight